# How to make files Archived using apex ? (isArchived = true)

Tags: trigger, files, contentdocument, fileupload, archive

I am in one of the requirements where I need to set `IsArchived = true` when user uploading any files using Upload files option.

I thought apex trigger will work here but it doesn't

```
trigger setFileArchived on ContentDocument (before insert) {
    for(ContentDocument ct : trigger.new){
        system.debug('---->'+ct.isArchived);
        ct.isArchived = true;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me to find a way?

Answer (score 0):

Having a look at the workbench for the object 'ContentDocument' we can see that the field **IsArchived** is updateable

https://workbench.developerforce.com/describe.php

The few things I'd recommend is

1. Match your case for the field name (you're using **isArchived** not **IsArchived**)
2. Use 'after insert' instead of 'before insert'

However, looking at the related questions, if  "[How to Create Archived Task](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/70852/how-to-create-archived-task)" is still up to date

> The archiving process occurs automatically on a background task provided by the system (I think every hour or so). You can't actually force the IsArchived flag to be set to true.

Comment: I did modify the code as per recommendations, but it seems result is as it is.
If the archiving process occurs automatically on a background task then do you know how can I make the file as archived when user upload ? any other option / work around.

Comment: @NailDavid Out of curiosity, why would you archive files automatically after the customer uploads them? Would it be worth creating your own 'Archived' checkbox that you could edit and filter on?